# Create custom property of a SPListCollection in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, splist, custom-properties, title

I have a SPListCollection that contains the lists of my site. All I want to do is to create a custom property that will be a dropdownlist with the lists names on it.

I know how to create a custom property, with this code:

```
public enum ImagesFolder
    {
        Inicio,
        Solutions
    };
    [Personalizable(), WebBrowsable(), Category("Carpeta imágenes")]
    public ImagesFolder ImageOption
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

But I can't stored on "ImagesFolder" the data obtained with that function:

```
    public Carrusel()
    {
        SPListCollection listaDocumentLibrary = SPContext.Current.Web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
        ArrayList listNames = new ArrayList();
        foreach (SPList oList in listaDocumentLibrary)
        {
            listNames.Add(oList.Title);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to develop a Custom Editor part for your web part, it will not work with enum. Please have a look at [Creating a Web Part with a Custom Editor Part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh228018(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to develop a Custom Editor part for your web part, it will not work with enum.

Please have a look at [Creating a Web Part with a Custom Editor Part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh228018(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks! I see the documentation but it is a but strange for me (i'm new on Sharepoint...) Could you help me a little bit more with some code or something like that?

Comment: You can contact me on email / skype, please look into my profile